# Dovecot ssl connection to mysql server

Tags: mysql, dovecot

Currently i am trying to setup the sql connection for my dovecot host. Because the sql server runs on another instance, i want to secure the connection with SSL. Sadly i can't find any options to configure that in Dovecot.

```
driver=mysql
connect = "host=1.2.3.4 dbname=vmail user=vmail password=xyz"
default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT
```

**Dovecot Version** 2.2.27

I can't find any informations about this.
Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Thanks,
Alex